# Does Spring actually start a new transaction with REQUIRES_NEW?

Tags: java, jboss, spring-transactions, spring-jms

My spring (4.1.1) application is deployed on a JBoss-6.10-final instance, so it uses the container-based transaction manager and data sources. For messaging, I use TIBCO EMS 8.1 with an XA queue connection factory set up. The Java version is 1.8.0_20. All of this is running on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop.

I need to send a request via JMS and then wait for the reply. The bean I’m calling from has transaction propagation set to Propagation.REQUIRED, so I need to send the request in a new transaction and then wait for the reply. This means the request is sent in a separate bean with transaction propagation set to Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW.
It works, but I’m getting a worrisome warning from JBoss:

> 14-10-02 12:06:12,902 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.tm.usertx.UserTransactionRegistry] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1)
>   Error notifying listener
>   org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionManager@1917b4de
>   of userTransactionStarted: java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Trying to
>   change transaction TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction:
>   0:ffff7f000101:126a:542d2010:d8 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING > in
>   enlist!** at
>   org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager$TxConnectionEventListener.enlist(TxConnectionManager.java:690)
>   at
>   org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.transactionStarted(TxConnectionManager.java:427)
>   at
>   org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionManager.userTransactionStarted(CachedConnectionManager.java:350)
>   at
>   org.jboss.tm.usertx.UserTransactionRegistry.userTransactionStarted(UserTransactionRegistry.java:119)
>   at
>   org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction.begin(ServerVMClientUserTransaction.java:141)
>   at
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doJtaBegin(JtaTransactionManager.java:875)
>   at
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doBegin(JtaTransactionManager.java:832)
>   at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.handleExistingTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:425)
>   at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:349)
>   at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:438)
>   at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:261)
>   at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy234.request(Unknown Source) at
>   com.izazi.ioriginate.framework.spring.jms.AbstractRequestReply.request(AbstractRequestReply.java:58)
>   at
>   com.izazi.ioriginate.service.addressvalidation.AddressValidationServiceImpl.validate(AddressValidationServiceImpl.java:34)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>   at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>   at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:266)
>   at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy235.validate(Unknown Source) at
>   com.izazi.ioriginate.services.dwr.AddressValidation.validate(AddressValidation.java:40)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at
>   org.directwebremoting.impl.ExecuteAjaxFilter.doFilter(ExecuteAjaxFilter.java:34)
>   at
>   org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter$1.doFilter(DefaultRemoter.java:428)
>   at
>   org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:431)
>   at
>   org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:283)
>   at
>   org.directwebremoting.servlet.PlainCallHandler.handle(PlainCallHandler.java:52)
>   at
>   org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:101)
>   at
>   org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:146)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:201)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:155)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>   at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181)
>   at
>   org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285)
>   at
>   org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261)
>   at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88)
>   at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve.invoke(RequestDumperValve.java:151)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

...and on the EMS side, I see some XA errors:

> johan@my_machine:~/opt/jboss-6.1.0.Final/bin$ 2014-10-02 10:43:15.801
>   ERROR: Transaction for non-existent consumer: 15 connID=16 sessID=20
>   {formatID=131076 gtrid_length=29 bqual_length=28
>   data=%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%FF%FF%7F%00%01%01%00%00%12jT-%0D*%00%00%00%AF1%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%FF%FF%7F%00%01%01%00%00%12jT-%0D*%00%00%00%B1}
>   2014-10-02 10:43:15.832 ERROR: Error processing xa end - transaction
>   marked ROLLBACKONLY, Exception. connID=16 sessID=20 {formatID=131076
>   gtrid_length=29 bqual_length=28
>   data=%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%FF%FF%7F%00%01%01%00%00%12jT-%0D*%00%00%00%AF1%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%FF%FF%7F%00%01%01%00%00%12jT-%0D*%00%00%00%B1}

After looking at the stack trace, I opened the source for Spring’s AbstractPlatformTransactionManager and came across the following code for handing of REQUIRES_NEW (starting at line 415):

```
if (definition.getPropagationBehavior() == TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW) {
    if (debugEnabled) {
        logger.debug("Suspending current transaction, creating new transaction with name [" +
                definition.getName() + "]");
    }
    SuspendedResourcesHolder suspendedResources = suspend(transaction);
    try {
        boolean newSynchronization = (getTransactionSynchronization() != SYNCHRONIZATION_NEVER);
        DefaultTransactionStatus status = newTransactionStatus(
                definition, transaction, true, newSynchronization, debugEnabled, suspendedResources);
        doBegin(transaction, definition);
        prepareSynchronization(status, definition);
        return status;
    }
    catch (RuntimeException beginEx) {
        resumeAfterBeginException(transaction, suspendedResources, beginEx);
        throw beginEx;
    }
    catch (Error beginErr) {
        resumeAfterBeginException(transaction, suspendedResources, beginErr);
        throw beginErr;
    }
}
```

**My question is: where is a new transaction being started?**

On the surface it looks like the existing transaction is being used instead of a new one being started - see how 'transaction' is being passed to doBegin(...). I looked in doBegin as well, and there is no indication of a new transaction being requested or created. This view appears to be supported by the stack trace and warning I get from JBoss...

Comment: I am not sure that looking there is going to help you in any way. I've seen this exception multiple times with JBoss and this was either a bug in JBoss itself or a wrong use of transaction semantics. If you're on 4.1.x, how about using the new `sendAndReceive` on the `JmsTemplate`? Going requires new to send the message immediately (if I understand your use case) is a bad idea

Comment: 1. Like I said: I am using JBoss 6.1.0-Final
2. sendAndReceive does not work in this context. The sequence of events are as follows when you try it:
a. Transaction starts
b. You send the message
c. You wait for the reply (which never comes because...)
d. transaction times out

Comment: The message only gets sent when the transaction commits, so if you want to do request-reply, you need to send the request in a separate transaction before going to wait for the reply...

Comment: Maybe you need to create your `JmsTemplate` with a non-XA `ConnectionFactory`? the `sendAndReceive` method is asking for a non transactional session anyway. If that does not work for you, please submit an issue with a project that reproduces the problem.

Comment: No, that won't work for me. I have to use an XA connection factory.

Comment: To do something outside a transaction? I don't get it.

Comment: I think you are missing the whole point here. What you describe is a workaround. I don't want a workaround. I want it to work as it should.

Comment: That's one way to look at it. You still don't explain why you have to use a XA connection factory for a non transactional operation. In any case, if you have a project that reproduces the issue we can certainly have a look to it.

Comment: By the way, it's not a workaround. If you are using  `REQUIRES_NEW` you cannot benefit from a temporary queue (i.e. you have to collect the reply on an existing queue) because your session is tied to your transaction and the message will be sent only when your new transaction commits. And when it does, your session will be closed and your temp destination will disappear. That's really less flexible than `convertAndSend`. I don't think anyone could help explaining the exception without the code

Comment: It works - temporary queue and all. Look at my post again. The stack trace entry in the log is a warning. I want to know why I'm getting a warning. In the previous version of our application we have similar scenarios but using ejb3 - not Spring. No warnings there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Happy to see that I'am not alone stuck in this ligthless hole...

As far as I got it, the deep cause of this warning is described [here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/145467) (end of the thread)

> when the outer transaction is suspended and the new inner transaction
>   started, the managed connection that Jboss connection pool retrieves
>   for the inner transaction is the same as that of the outer
>   transaction, which is causing the IllegalStateException to get thrown!

and is due to a specific behavior of the jboss JCA contract implementation (`Lazy JCA enlistment`).

[A defect has been opened on spring side](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5423), flagged as "won't fix" but they provide a workaround configuration :

> The typical solution is to use Spring's
>   TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy and switch the
>   "reobtainTransactionalConnections" flag to "true" there

Have fun !

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot of sense